# How can i get ssm parameter from other region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm, aws-api-gateway

I have a template for deploying a Cognito user pool in "eu-west-1" and other template for deploying my APIGateway and usage plan in "us-east-1". I have the parameters section in this way:

```
Parameters:
  CognitoAPP:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Description: 'Cognito App client saved in eu-west-1'
  CognitoUPId:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Description: 'Cognito parameter saved in eu-west-1'
```

which are got from JSON parameters:

```
{
    "Parameters": {
        "CognitoAPP": "/playground/historical-api/cognito-app-client",
        "CognitoUPId": "/playground/historical-api/cognito-user-pool-id"        }
}
```

"CognitoAPP" and "CognitoUPId" are saved in "eu-west-1" and I would like to get them in "us-east-1".

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with plain CFN. You would have to create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in a form of a lambda function. The function would use AWS SDK to query your SSM in different region and return to your stack for further use.